# Storing data in a multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, multidimensional-array

I am storing this data in a 10x5 matrix but when I get to the 4 position of the first row I have this error "**Exception in thread" AWT-EventQueue-0 "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5**". I think the error is in **listPatients[0][counter]** but I do not know what to do.

```
public class PatientForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

       Patient[][] patientList;

        int counter;

    public PatientForm() {
        initComponents();

        patientList = new Patient[10][5];

        counter = 0;
    }


  private void btnasignarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
            if (counter < listPatients.length) {
            String identification = txtidentification.getText();
            String name= txtname.getText();
            String lastName = txtlastName.getText();
            String eps = txteps.getText();
            boolean type = jrbtipo1.isSelected();
            String diagnosis = txtdiagnostico.getText();

                Patient objPatient = new Patient(identification, name, lastName, eps, type, diagnosis);


                listPatients[0][counter] = objPatient;
                counter++;

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Head" + counter + " Patients.");
            }else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You are not checking if the counter is exceeding the array length i.e. 5. So if this method will be called more than that it will always generate an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `10x5` matrix means you can use indexes of the array from [0-9][0-4]. That is why you are receiving an IndexOutOfBound Exception.
You are trying to access `listPatients[0][5]`. The second index value is 5, which is not available. The last index of any row of that array is `listPatients[0-9][4]`.

Check your counter value because it is 5 somehow. Fix this value or validate this value before accessing any index of that array.

Comment: @Thomas use `listPatients[0][4]` . it was a general way of telling indexes `listPatients [0-9] [4]`.

Comment: Is there any way to make it work only with the counter?

Comment: @ThomasCaycedoMartinez No, because its a 2D array. you have to specify both indexes if you want to get exactly one patient. if you want to get single array of patients then you ll get by  `Patient[] singleList =listPatients[0] `;